# Fluid full height column, sticky footer

Tags: css, footer

I'm sure this is easy but I'm stuck.

I have a simple demo here to illustrate.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/

It's a container width a max-width(fluid).

The right column is a set width but the left column is fluid and the footer is sticky at the bottom.

I just need to extend the height of the left column (yellow) so it is 100%, it touches the footer

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Title of the document</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">

      <style type="text/css">
        /*--stickyFooter--*/
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
        }

        #wrap {
          min-height: 100%;
          max-width:1000px;
          margin:0 auto;
          border-left:20px solid white;
          border-right:20px solid white;
        }

        #main {
          overflow:auto;
          padding-bottom: 150px;/* must be same height as the footer */
          height:100%;
          min-height:100%;
        }  

        footer {
          position: relative;
            margin:-150px auto 0 auto;
            height: 150px;
            clear:both;
            max-width:1000px;
            background:red;
            border-left:20px solid white;
          border-right:20px solid white;
        } 

        body:before {/*Opera Fix*/
            content:"";
            height:100%;
            float:left;
            width:0;
            margin-top:-32767px;/
        }
        /*--END-stickyFooter--*/

        header{
          height:100px;
          background:#ddd;
        }
        #rightCol{
          height:100px;
          background:#eee;
          width:200px;
          float:left;
        }
        #leftCol{
          margin-left:210px;
          background:yellow;
          height:auto;
          height:100%;
        }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>

      <div id="wrap">

        <header>
          <h2>Header</h2>
        </header>

        <div id="main">
          <div id="rightCol">
           <h2>Right Col</h2>
          </div><!-- #rightCol -->
          <div id="leftCol">
            <h2>Left Col</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div><!-- #leftCol -->
        </div>  

      </div><!--wrap-->

      <footer>
        <div id="footer-container">
          <h2>Footer</h2>
        </div><!-- #footer-container -->
      </footer>  

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: you can achieve fluid height with jquery.

Comment: wanna try? I can write code for you!

Comment: I can try but I was hoping for a CSS solution

Comment: ya we can do it tru css as well with position absolute. look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

```
#leftCol {
position: absolute;
width: 789px;
}
```